# Most efficient way to determine lowest valid number within a big range by only knowing whether your guess is too low

Tags: python, algorithm

Let's assume you want to guess a certain number(x) within a big range in Python.

A simple external validation function, which you can call as many times as needed, will give you hints:

- If the number being tested is equal to or higher than the lowest valid number, it will, in both cases, return `True` (you may not know explicitly if the number being tested is too high).
- Else (if the number is too low) it will return `False`.

What would be the most efficient way to determine the smallest possible valid number? Is there a non-linear approach?

Comment: Isn't this just binary search between zero and the input number? (assuming positive integers only)

Comment: what is the characteristic of the numbers - is that in sorted order?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: See [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: What is the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about *most efficient*, but here is a quite efficient algorithm. It first searches the order of magnitude by taking successive powers of 2. Then it uses dichotomy to narrow down the actual number:

```
num = 123

lowest = 0
guess  = 1

check = lambda : guess >= num

i=0
# find order of magnitude
while not check():
    i+=1
    #print(guess)
    lowest = guess
    guess = guess*2

# find number
highest = guess
while lowest != highest-1:
    i+=1
    guess = (highest+lowest)//2
    #print(lowest, guess, highest)
    if check():
        highest = guess
    else:
        lowest = guess
        
guess = highest

print(f'found {guess} in {i} steps')
```

Example with 123:  `found 123 in 13 steps`

Example with 123456789:  `found 123456789 in 53 steps`

*NB. You can uncomment the `print` to see the intermediate steps*

Comment: Can't this be optimized by using binary search on the power of 2? that is if we know a maximum value ...

Comment: @Surt we know a maximum (or equal) after the first loop. Please provide your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
  def validation(number, answer):
   if answer > number:
      return True
   return False
```

The number parameter is the number you are trying to guess.

Comment: You can just `return answer > number`, but this doesn't answer the question since it doesn't return a number